# Is it possible to only use children of the main childelement in the scatterview as scatteritems?

Tags: wpf, touch, pixelsense, scatterview, raddocking

I'm using the Telerik api to take use of docking and my xaml looks something like this:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:myControl="clr-namespace:TouchControl.Controls"
        xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ve="clr-namespace:InfoStrat.VE.WPFTouch;assembly=InfoStrat.VE.WPFTouch"
        xmlns:surface="http://schemas.microsoft.com/surface/2008"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="TouchControl.MainWindow"
        Title="TestTouch" WindowStartupLocation="Manual" WindowState="Normal" Topmost="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Icon="/TouchControl;component/images/icon.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#00000000" FontFamily="Traditional Arabic" SizeToContent="Height" BorderThickness="0,5" BorderBrush="Black" AllowsTransparency="False">


        <Grid>
            <telerik:RadDocking Height="1080" Width="1920" telerik:RadDocking.FloatingLocation="890,540" Margin="0,0,-16,-38" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" HasDocumentHost="False">
                <telerik:RadSplitContainer Height="1080" Width="1920" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" InitialPosition="FloatingOnly" Loaded="RadSplitContainer_Loaded">
                    <telerik:RadPaneGroup x:Name="RadPanelGroupChart" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <telerik:RadPane x:Name="RadPanelChart" Header="Chart" CanFloat="True" CanUserClose="true" CanUserPin="False">
                            <myControl:ChartControl HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </telerik:RadPane>
                    </telerik:RadPaneGroup>

            </telerik:RadSplitContainer>
        </telerik:RadDocking>
```

Is it possible to implement the ScatterView as a parent to "Raddocking", but choose to only effect the RadPane?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The ScatterView control cannot magically make other controls act as though they were designed to be used with multitouch.  You'll need to either tell Telerik that you'd like them to provide a multitouch version of their docking controls (and others) or recreate that functionaltiy on your own.

Comment: What i really mean, is that i want to be able to use interactive user controls within the scatterview. e.g a Bing Maps controller. But if i do that now, and try to move on the bing maps, scatterview thinks that i want to move the controller. It looks like i have to make a frame for the controllers (And put the interactive controller within it), and make manual multitouch for that frame.